# updating webgl-surface-plot based on user input

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

I am trying to use [webgl-surface-plot](http://code.google.com/p/webgl-surface-plot/) to plot in 3D. the issue is, i want to take in user inputs for the parameters of my function using sliders or text boxes. for some reason though, I cannot get it to update the graph when the slider/text box is updated. any help is appreciated. currently I am using an html5 slider for simplicity until I can figure out other larger issues.

Comment: Note: I get it to work, but at the moment, I have to delete the whole canvas object. I was wondering if there was a way to update it without having to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expose the **JSSurfacePlot.data** object as well as the **redraw** function to your calling code. Modifying the former before calling the latter should do the trick.

**update**

Just call the 'draw(...)' method with the new data.